# Increase frequency of yticks pandas log plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a pandas plot which i want to increase the frequency of the ticks on the y axis. This is what i am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import numpy as np
import random
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('exp-mediciones-grales-data.csv', sep=', ', engine='python')

iteraciones = str(df.loc[0]["iteraciones_totales"]) + " iteraciones"

# filtro datos
filtro = []
tams = {128, 512, 1024, 2048}
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    filtro.append(df.loc[i]["implementation"] not in {'asm-lu'} and df.loc[i]["width"] in tams)
df = df[filtro]
# print df

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12.0,6.0 # seteo tamaño en inches (default: 8.0, 6.0)
ax = sns.barplot(x="width", y="cycles", hue="implementation", data=df)
ax.set_xlabel("Width (#pxs)".decode('utf-8'))
ax.set_ylabel("Cant. ciclos")
ax.set_title(("Comparación ciclos totales - lena.bmp - escala log. - " + iteraciones).decode('utf-8'))
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(numticks=10)
print(ax.yaxis.get_major_locator())
print(ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator())
print(ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter())
print(ax.yaxis.get_minor_formatter())
ax.grid();
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.savefig('img/comp-ciclos-gral.png')
plt.show()
```

Which is reading the following csv file (note that this is just a fragment of the real csv due its size):

```
cache-misses, branch-misses, cycles, implementation, iteracion_actual, iteraciones_totales, width, height, filename
754514, 38296, 21245838, gcc-O0, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746642, 42645, 4790757, gcc-O1, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
765683, 43293, 4876918, gcc-O2, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
760192, 43686, 4863607, gcc-O3, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753015, 43097, 20955130, clang-O0, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
741422, 43058, 4903846, clang-O1, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
782010, 47015, 4902117, clang-O2, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
744953, 43055, 5136768, clang-O3, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
744279, 35906, 2020977, asm-normal, 0, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746337, 40349, 21038198, gcc-O0, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753977, 41595, 4819412, gcc-O1, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748332, 40377, 4802812, gcc-O2, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
769454, 45438, 4780094, gcc-O3, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
759925, 41473, 20954339, clang-O0, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757489, 45501, 5030679, clang-O1, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756380, 44303, 5027996, clang-O2, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
761244, 47973, 4673384, clang-O3, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748213, 53849, 2912014, asm-normal, 1, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
771935, 45702, 21726418, gcc-O0, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
771014, 49302, 7337226, gcc-O1, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748409, 40508, 4902920, gcc-O2, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
763494, 42859, 5087846, gcc-O3, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752759, 40197, 20764154, clang-O0, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
774508, 47920, 4867361, clang-O1, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753801, 42909, 4750186, clang-O2, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752768, 42246, 4637759, clang-O3, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
750644, 41245, 2024802, asm-normal, 2, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
766891, 44323, 20833280, gcc-O0, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
769412, 45713, 4797448, gcc-O1, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758406, 44985, 4772476, gcc-O2, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
762121, 39249, 4781333, gcc-O3, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
761684, 40620, 20735225, clang-O0, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
760735, 43452, 4759958, clang-O1, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
770116, 44324, 6192036, clang-O2, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
765265, 40187, 4745089, clang-O3, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
761596, 46812, 2065423, asm-normal, 3, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
770834, 44902, 21985456, gcc-O0, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
770537, 43002, 4889225, gcc-O1, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
764481, 44417, 4820004, gcc-O2, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
772690, 43796, 5137793, gcc-O3, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
763171, 45014, 20880990, clang-O0, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
775922, 46399, 5271763, clang-O1, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755454, 44722, 4729576, clang-O2, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756834, 41189, 4753464, clang-O3, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756965, 41895, 2006790, asm-normal, 4, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753787, 41179, 20771218, gcc-O0, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757335, 43153, 4751041, gcc-O1, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755210, 40113, 4794224, gcc-O2, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748250, 42506, 5124744, gcc-O3, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749921, 43060, 20824903, clang-O0, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757251, 45729, 6866250, clang-O1, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756954, 43234, 4822980, clang-O2, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755756, 39777, 4705682, clang-O3, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755947, 46913, 2020015, asm-normal, 5, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746311, 42252, 21054447, gcc-O0, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755585, 44218, 4758237, gcc-O1, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752079, 40596, 4724156, gcc-O2, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753537, 41058, 4756946, gcc-O3, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
747427, 42737, 21106814, clang-O0, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755322, 42426, 4838250, clang-O1, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752073, 42118, 5187271, clang-O2, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755120, 39742, 4705393, clang-O3, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758045, 44831, 2040639, asm-normal, 6, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754630, 44534, 20742332, gcc-O0, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756139, 41244, 4750709, gcc-O1, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755538, 40202, 4727678, gcc-O2, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748134, 40226, 5238171, gcc-O3, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754617, 45466, 20659709, clang-O0, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755723, 41178, 4756899, clang-O1, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
745005, 39904, 5183487, clang-O2, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755787, 41168, 4719343, clang-O3, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757174, 40961, 2006045, asm-normal, 7, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755939, 43058, 20755581, gcc-O0, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754415, 42244, 4752627, gcc-O1, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753190, 41540, 4728938, gcc-O2, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758080, 42755, 4792196, gcc-O3, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754469, 41842, 20692363, clang-O0, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755182, 40984, 4764771, clang-O1, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749631, 41322, 5189490, clang-O2, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
764774, 42266, 4682398, clang-O3, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758403, 44775, 2011267, asm-normal, 8, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754154, 41838, 20652785, gcc-O0, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755429, 44137, 4725693, gcc-O1, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
761931, 43701, 4743581, gcc-O2, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754843, 41791, 4781016, gcc-O3, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755443, 41437, 20702197, clang-O0, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756258, 43281, 4844985, clang-O1, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
763326, 44422, 4732688, clang-O2, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755462, 45454, 4728088, clang-O3, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758925, 42772, 2107745, asm-normal, 9, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755851, 41753, 20684557, gcc-O0, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754554, 41787, 4765849, gcc-O1, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754567, 42614, 4798011, gcc-O2, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756294, 44396, 4779785, gcc-O3, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755954, 43808, 20688778, clang-O0, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
763619, 40587, 4809870, clang-O1, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752827, 41195, 4811872, clang-O2, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756459, 41251, 4631233, clang-O3, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752892, 41518, 2016069, asm-normal, 10, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748976, 39866, 21032278, gcc-O0, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755269, 39663, 4757945, gcc-O1, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756480, 42188, 4813842, gcc-O2, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756315, 39931, 4789761, gcc-O3, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
759314, 42071, 20698109, clang-O0, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755522, 42142, 4839857, clang-O1, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754173, 40986, 4800536, clang-O2, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756537, 41801, 4629855, clang-O3, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749411, 41928, 2350016, asm-normal, 11, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756189, 41661, 20684176, gcc-O0, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756898, 41047, 4785846, gcc-O1, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757663, 40092, 4772384, gcc-O2, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
737711, 40144, 4718587, gcc-O3, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757693, 46441, 20682281, clang-O0, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757447, 42354, 4818892, clang-O1, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
751416, 43334, 5257720, clang-O2, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748832, 43082, 5116003, clang-O3, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758113, 43870, 2010932, asm-normal, 12, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754536, 40235, 20764551, gcc-O0, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
765167, 40323, 4797240, gcc-O1, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754728, 40806, 4765800, gcc-O2, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749403, 40226, 5205495, gcc-O3, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758349, 40843, 20734436, clang-O0, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748312, 42537, 5289810, clang-O1, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754799, 43023, 5266759, clang-O2, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
760250, 39257, 4621381, clang-O3, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757238, 44146, 2116889, asm-normal, 13, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748161, 40372, 21050141, gcc-O0, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757421, 38988, 4702438, gcc-O1, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755734, 39997, 4724957, gcc-O2, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755982, 43728, 4787955, gcc-O3, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755079, 41091, 20731825, clang-O0, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
752491, 40965, 5114668, clang-O1, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
750067, 41283, 5245832, clang-O2, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753189, 44716, 4797891, clang-O3, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
745971, 43551, 2361982, asm-normal, 14, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758392, 41009, 20684474, gcc-O0, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755816, 41798, 4698093, gcc-O1, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756633, 40684, 4724908, gcc-O2, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758025, 43860, 4793704, gcc-O3, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749638, 42105, 20734407, clang-O0, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748328, 40582, 5262166, clang-O1, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757886, 42200, 4806499, clang-O2, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
748533, 42087, 4645995, clang-O3, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756079, 42616, 2015162, asm-normal, 15, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753047, 43065, 20806196, gcc-O0, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755831, 42264, 4767602, gcc-O1, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753975, 41338, 4748444, gcc-O2, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756919, 43763, 4791000, gcc-O3, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756201, 39454, 21325878, clang-O0, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754824, 40237, 4763613, clang-O1, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755604, 39707, 4815284, clang-O2, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755563, 41286, 4627740, clang-O3, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754539, 45252, 2011022, asm-normal, 16, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756568, 43443, 20769372, gcc-O0, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
745927, 39023, 5077950, gcc-O1, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758873, 39222, 4812323, gcc-O2, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757944, 43371, 4796671, gcc-O3, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757098, 41913, 20716791, clang-O0, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
767497, 39063, 4828153, clang-O1, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755647, 40152, 4765764, clang-O2, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
762528, 43961, 4729931, clang-O3, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
751928, 44062, 2035497, asm-normal, 17, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755982, 44476, 20833263, gcc-O0, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757408, 40447, 4700997, gcc-O1, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754597, 40130, 4820744, gcc-O2, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756885, 40237, 4728415, gcc-O3, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753141, 38524, 20922561, clang-O0, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754579, 40769, 4820082, clang-O1, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755888, 40570, 4733563, clang-O2, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
744889, 40743, 5087221, clang-O3, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753024, 41619, 2024990, asm-normal, 18, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757684, 41963, 20756745, gcc-O0, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756766, 41737, 4810924, gcc-O1, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
747393, 38867, 5200795, gcc-O2, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756376, 40449, 4726569, gcc-O3, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
747503, 39379, 21097518, clang-O0, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
759718, 41029, 4812129, clang-O1, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746864, 41799, 5180624, clang-O2, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753795, 41224, 4625117, clang-O3, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
745630, 44071, 2343712, asm-normal, 19, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758224, 42863, 20769005, gcc-O0, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756053, 42619, 4704123, gcc-O1, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756155, 39533, 4785592, gcc-O2, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757610, 42323, 4787617, gcc-O3, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
755039, 39486, 20735615, clang-O0, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756296, 42808, 4757506, clang-O1, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746233, 42690, 4908488, clang-O2, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
733654, 46839, 5248805, clang-O3, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
773089, 43984, 2381311, asm-normal, 20, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749376, 44383, 21338286, gcc-O0, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
760813, 41513, 4700901, gcc-O1, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
729506, 42770, 4720759, gcc-O2, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
771178, 41187, 4799921, gcc-O3, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
751276, 39337, 21139196, clang-O0, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749849, 42556, 4811493, clang-O1, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
738811, 42304, 4823182, clang-O2, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
768234, 40484, 4714294, clang-O3, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756794, 47570, 2097725, asm-normal, 21, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
762160, 43765, 20679071, gcc-O0, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758144, 41893, 4764746, gcc-O1, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754025, 40188, 4753167, gcc-O2, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
770198, 41037, 4802287, gcc-O3, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
751743, 41068, 20832922, clang-O0, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
759385, 42188, 4819840, clang-O1, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
757798, 43571, 4744708, clang-O2, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
753673, 41223, 4678249, clang-O3, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758835, 42347, 2015159, asm-normal, 22, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
754211, 41488, 21145849, gcc-O0, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749848, 42428, 5095584, gcc-O1, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
760108, 41064, 4764720, gcc-O2, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758643, 39135, 4783275, gcc-O3, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749615, 40781, 21103897, clang-O0, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
756925, 41620, 4767282, clang-O1, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
765955, 42128, 4774779, clang-O2, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
758532, 41833, 4628979, clang-O3, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
745506, 45894, 1996381, asm-normal, 23, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
738742, 43376, 20802040, gcc-O0, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
764938, 40085, 4733898, gcc-O1, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
746568, 42709, 4734854, gcc-O2, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
749192, 41114, 4760271, gcc-O3, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
778000, 40942, 20757609, clang-O0, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
765451, 42403, 4818254, clang-O1, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
764545, 38903, 4746840, clang-O2, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
759404, 38145, 4670539, clang-O3, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
743472, 43736, 2351174, asm-normal, 24, 25, 1536, 768, lena-1536x768.bmp
18263, 10082, 438012, gcc-O0, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22259, 10887, 221996, gcc-O1, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21634, 10804, 144726, gcc-O2, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24368, 10775, 243738, gcc-O3, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20889, 11092, 420608, clang-O0, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23714, 10933, 184647, clang-O1, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21233, 10836, 123994, clang-O2, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23978, 10960, 162840, clang-O3, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
18978, 9520, 46237, asm-normal, 0, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23495, 10544, 425357, gcc-O0, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24055, 10930, 207720, gcc-O1, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21869, 10966, 149752, gcc-O2, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24502, 10789, 229436, gcc-O3, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24114, 10853, 421399, clang-O0, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22898, 11028, 183315, clang-O1, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21490, 11057, 104638, clang-O2, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23284, 11108, 147254, clang-O3, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22233, 10461, 45081, asm-normal, 1, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20470, 10757, 433525, gcc-O0, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24612, 10874, 208926, gcc-O1, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21694, 10879, 150256, gcc-O2, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24602, 10855, 217600, gcc-O3, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21268, 11017, 416188, clang-O0, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24093, 10912, 184486, clang-O1, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24925, 10969, 105889, clang-O2, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22421, 10989, 101976, clang-O3, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22623, 10567, 46439, asm-normal, 2, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22065, 10875, 535448, gcc-O0, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24997, 10876, 144472, gcc-O1, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23556, 11111, 131732, gcc-O2, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23960, 10861, 228860, gcc-O3, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21487, 10859, 420021, clang-O0, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25055, 10920, 118424, clang-O1, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20426, 11108, 111919, clang-O2, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24447, 11046, 162376, clang-O3, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22271, 10397, 56596, asm-normal, 3, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23480, 10794, 426790, gcc-O0, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23921, 10867, 209426, gcc-O1, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25334, 11038, 128565, gcc-O2, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24048, 10952, 217771, gcc-O3, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21938, 11112, 464678, clang-O0, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23935, 10696, 182859, clang-O1, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25639, 11311, 111200, clang-O2, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22576, 11010, 89125, clang-O3, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24818, 10413, 58561, asm-normal, 4, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24730, 10618, 439816, gcc-O0, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22151, 10997, 187830, gcc-O1, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21974, 11186, 126625, gcc-O2, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
32023, 11087, 123475, gcc-O3, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25643, 11304, 570927, clang-O0, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21937, 11023, 127624, clang-O1, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23373, 10982, 101111, clang-O2, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
34669, 10832, 87874, clang-O3, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22593, 10605, 46708, asm-normal, 5, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21782, 10685, 523184, gcc-O0, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22616, 10845, 117247, gcc-O1, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25010, 10868, 127596, gcc-O2, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23390, 10993, 126360, gcc-O3, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21781, 10921, 434999, clang-O0, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26322, 11083, 146349, clang-O1, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22218, 11056, 107527, clang-O2, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26098, 10774, 124848, clang-O3, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22317, 10358, 45344, asm-normal, 6, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25784, 10830, 647917, gcc-O0, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23700, 11134, 118106, gcc-O1, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25697, 11230, 126666, gcc-O2, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25638, 10784, 209309, gcc-O3, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21828, 10810, 434589, clang-O0, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25046, 10779, 129084, clang-O1, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21605, 10884, 128144, clang-O2, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24097, 10997, 85212, clang-O3, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25944, 10382, 50524, asm-normal, 7, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23424, 10338, 626646, gcc-O0, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23308, 10726, 117511, gcc-O1, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22008, 11049, 127299, gcc-O2, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22077, 10838, 144287, gcc-O3, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21153, 10858, 420943, clang-O0, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21719, 11205, 151575, clang-O1, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24750, 10914, 108632, clang-O2, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21859, 11192, 123932, clang-O3, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26487, 10511, 50963, asm-normal, 8, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25760, 10968, 434084, gcc-O0, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26667, 11201, 194320, gcc-O1, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21960, 11159, 150068, gcc-O2, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24783, 10899, 126024, gcc-O3, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22272, 10878, 435424, clang-O0, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24083, 11023, 102624, clang-O1, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20913, 10863, 128632, clang-O2, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25856, 11059, 124018, clang-O3, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22514, 10508, 52826, asm-normal, 9, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24378, 10710, 440158, gcc-O0, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22788, 11308, 193645, gcc-O1, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22023, 10850, 125528, gcc-O2, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23177, 11033, 123095, gcc-O3, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21255, 11155, 518592, clang-O0, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22544, 10941, 99623, clang-O1, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24951, 10822, 129404, clang-O2, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23570, 11067, 85649, clang-O3, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25650, 10572, 52211, asm-normal, 10, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23503, 10797, 439659, gcc-O0, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25949, 11125, 141888, gcc-O1, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23023, 11029, 123632, gcc-O2, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20829, 11003, 139634, gcc-O3, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26280, 11018, 644628, clang-O0, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22292, 11001, 113951, clang-O1, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21420, 10909, 159300, clang-O2, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21499, 10961, 86057, clang-O3, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22694, 10499, 46621, asm-normal, 11, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23403, 10856, 562298, gcc-O0, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22140, 10891, 117205, gcc-O1, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23660, 11084, 123549, gcc-O2, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23539, 10821, 151392, gcc-O3, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
27985, 11006, 475832, clang-O0, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22279, 10918, 122393, clang-O1, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24061, 10890, 158968, clang-O2, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25750, 11076, 99186, clang-O3, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26110, 10527, 48791, asm-normal, 12, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23974, 10690, 753703, gcc-O0, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22116, 10956, 144520, gcc-O1, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24755, 11011, 205058, gcc-O2, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25306, 10885, 127869, gcc-O3, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21672, 10883, 416280, clang-O0, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22733, 10972, 122916, clang-O1, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26310, 11345, 334848, clang-O2, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25124, 10750, 87346, clang-O3, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
22044, 10410, 54449, asm-normal, 13, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
26052, 10708, 793404, gcc-O0, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
21695, 10843, 121353, gcc-O1, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24940, 10908, 150532, gcc-O2, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24149, 10722, 150344, gcc-O3, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24022, 10881, 672100, clang-O0, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
24956, 10840, 104922, clang-O1, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
23962, 10954, 185405, clang-O2, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
20915, 10948, 92153, clang-O3, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
25735, 10402, 57596, asm-normal, 14, 25, 128, 128, lena-128x128.bmp
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see, i tried setting the number of ticks to the major locator but it's not doing what i want. I just want to increment the frequency of the labels values. More precisely, i would want to display more values than the powers of 10. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, log scale axis will only label ticks only at integer powers of base, i.e. major ticks. In order to show the labeling of ticks that are not at integer powers of base (potentially minor ticks), you will need to use one of the `matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter` to setup proper `minor_thresholds` as [documented](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter):

> In some cases such as the colorbar, there is no distinction between major and minor ticks; the tick locations might be set manually, or by a locator that puts ticks at integer powers of base and at intermediate locations. For this situation, disable the minor_thresholds logic by using minor_thresholds=(np.inf, np.inf), so that all ticks will be labeled.

You might also want to set minor ticks so that their labels will not overlap. Here is my example:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'width': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'cycles': [2e5, 3e6, 4e7, 7e5, 8e6, 9e7],
                   'implementation': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']})
ax = sns.barplot(x="width", y="cycles", hue="implementation", data=df)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=[2,3,5,7]))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation(minor_thresholds=(np.inf, np.inf)))
```

[image]